# Display two views at once and change url on change

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have a main view with a menu which helps me display another view. It's similar to this:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="menu">
            <a href="controller/page1">Page1</a>
            <a href="controller/page2">Page2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
            <!-- Page1 or Page2 are displayed here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using php's Yii framework. Which makes me not to use `<?php include("menuview.php"); ?>`. So I'm looking for a different solution. I can do this with Ajax, but I would also like the link to change to mypage/controller/Page2. With Ajax I can only get it to this: mypage/controller/index#Page2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main view, instead of include do

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_page1', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

*protected/views/controller/page1.php* and *protected/views/controller/page2.php* content at your liking

*protected/views/layouts/custom.php:*

```
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
<div id="page">
    <div id="menu">
        <?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Page1', array('controller/page1'), array('update' => '#content')); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Page2', array('controller/page2'), array('update' => '#content')); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

*protected/controllers/ControllerController.php:*

```
class ControllerController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views.
     */
    public $layout = '//layouts/custom';

    public function actionPage1() {
        if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            $this->renderPartial('page1');
        else
            $this->render('page1');
    }

    public function actionPage2() {
        if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            $this->renderPartial('page2');
        else
            $this->render('page2');
    }

}
```

**UPDATE2:**

If you need the link in address bar to change too then your only option is to use regular link and not ajax `<?php echo CHtml::link('Page1', array('controller/page1')); ?>`

using ajax the preferred way is using hash like you mentioned.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I would like to call my Controller to render the view.

Comment: updated the answer, if this is not what you need you should describe more precisely what you need.

Comment: Before I've seen this, I've added an if statement inside my main layout that would include my menu if I'm in a certain controller, but your solution is way more elegant. Thank you very much for this!